# Job failover handling in Zookeeper

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zookeeper, high-availability, failover

I'm running a Zookeeper ensemble consisting of three machines, one Mesos master as the leader and the other two as followers. I've seen that if I deliberately fail/stop the current Mesos master, then any one among the other two followers will be elected as the Mesos master. This is expected behavior I understand.

My question is, if I submit a job via a framework and during the job execution if the current Mesos master fails, then how will the remaining tasks in that job be handled by the next elected Mesos leader?

For example, say during the execution of the sparkPi example if the current Mesos master fails then how do I tell the next elected master to pick up the tasks from where the last master left them? Will this failover be handled automatically by the zookeeper or does it require any configuration changes.

Answer (score 0):

Failover would be handled by ZooKeeper and Mesos framework. Referring to the documentation: http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.1/running-on-mesos.html you would see that when you run in Mesos master HA mode you need to specify zookeeper quorum instead of the Mesos master: `mesos://zk://host1:port1,host2:port2,...` or `mesos://zk://host1:port1,host2:port2,.../mesos`